# Null values to be ignored while encrypting data in R

Tags: r

I am working on Encrypting certain columns of dataframe bulky (millions of records) with Below code:

```
df$p_enc <- sapply ( df$p,digest, "crc32" )
```

However the columns has a lot of NA values i dont want then to encrypt.
Infact i want R to skip NA them while running the encryption code.

I tried using :

```
df$p_enc<-sapply(df$p,digest,"crc32",na.omit)
df$p_enc<-sapply(df$p,digest,"crc32",na.pass)
df$p_enc<-sapply(df$p,digest,"crc32",na.exclude)
```

Getting following Error:

> Error in serialize && !file : invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'

Comment: Have u tried: `df$p_enc<-sapply(na.omit(df$p),digest,"crc32",na.omit)`

Comment: Another option would be to initialize as `NA`, then run the encryption over a subset: `df$p_enc <- NA; df$p_enc[!is.na(df$p)] <- sapply(df$p[!is.na(df$p)], digest, "crc32")`

Comment: Thanks LAP you code works fine..saved me a lot of effort.